# How were the video broadcasts from the Moon made on Apollo 11?

Tags: nasa

First Neil was taking photos then there was a video camera showing both Buzz and Neil in the picture, and the video is showing Neil is still taking photos of Buzz sticking some weather thing! So prove me wrong please, if that was a live feed, where is the cable from the video recorder to the space craft so they can transmit to all on earth?

they were the only two there on the moon the third man, mr. M Collins he was still hovering in the space craft he was never on the moon.

How did that happen?

Comment: Do you have a link to the video you're referring to?

Comment: Related question (not a duplicate though): http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2993/how-did-nasa-achieve-their-live-tv-broadcast-in-1969

Answer (score 7):

Apollo 11 carried a [single B&W TV camera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_TV_camera#Westinghouse_Apollo_Lunar_Television_Camera). It was installed on a tray in a storage compartment on the LM. This tray could be folded out to give a view of the ladder. This position was used to make the 'first step' footage. This is a photo of a mockup of the lander, with the tray in the open position.

[image: TV camera on tray]

Later on, one of the astronauts removed the camera from this tray and placed it on a [tripod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Apollo_11_TV_Camera.JPG).

[image: Apollo 11 TV camera]

You can see the cable running from the tripod to the lander (out of frame on the left).

Comment: IIRC *Moonscape* also has a pretty good sequence showing when the astronauts were setting up the camera. http://moonscapemovie.blogspot.com/ (also available on Youtube). I don't remember exactly which part covered that, though, but if I have to take a guess (can't check beyond the title at the moment) it'd be [TV and Flag Setup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Brk2cvbbGTc).