# What did Apollo 11's SSTV signal sound like?

Tags: nasa, apollo-program, apollo-11

The TV signal from Apollo 11 had limited bandwidth, and an [oddball format](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2993/how-did-nasa-achieve-their-live-tv-broadcast-in-1969) was used to send and convert the signal.

All of the [modern SSTV demos](https://youtu.be/sG4UhlByFyw?t=55) I've seen on YouTube seem to take around a minute to transfer one frame.

In 1969, if you had receiver big enough on earth to listen to Apollo 11's radio signal, would the SSTV tones be audible? And would it be a similar sound to modern SSTV formats?

I can't find much information on this, and it seems no recordings exist sadly.

Comment: @Uwe: The "tones", going by the video, appear to be the actual signal for the image.

Comment: See this NASA [paper](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/ApolloTV-Acrobat7.pdf) on page 7. "A  320  horizontal  progressive  line,  10  frame  per  second,  format  was  chosen  to  fit  in  this  space.    This  slow-scan  format  used  only  one-tenth  of  the  5  MHz bandwidth of the 525 interlaced lines, 30 frames per second format that was standard for television in the United States at the time." So the SSTV signal bandwidth was about 500 kHz, much more than hearable. The 10 frames per second was too low to be heard but the 3.2 kHz line frequency may be hearable.

Comment: @Uwe Thanks! That great PDF answers my question. Hopefully one day someone recreates a software version of the 10fps encoder/decoder, it would be interesting to see it work in realtime.